# My Rigges are moving other parts of the model

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

[image]

I created this model. I have rigged the entire model and I have individually parented the model to the individual rigges.

For some reason if I rotate one of the rigges, it moves a different leg. Why is that?

*Before moving the rig*
[image]

*After moving the rig*
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You only need one rig. You only need one bone per leg segment unless there is extra geometry in there and you want each segment to be bendy. Parent your combined mesh to the armature and choose Armature deform -> With automatic weights. Should be good to go.